# Why in member center "App Store and Ad Hoc" certificate (production) is not available?

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile

I don't really get why the button is not available?
My role is `Admin`, also i get `Agent` account. The story is same.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've deleted one of 3 Distribution Cer. and button for creation new one become enabled. 
And all of APNS cer. was ok.
in total what we got: 
We can have 3 distribution cer.
Revoke distribution cer (not APNS cer) is save for APNS.

Comment: I think what Evgeniy is trying to say is that you can only have a maximum of 3 Ad Hoc certificates active at any one time. In order to add another one you must revoke a previous certificate.

Answer (score 3):

To Manage Your apps use the below url to login.

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa

Above certificate is used for development and it will not differ based on the role you have. In the member center you will have both adhoc and distribution certificates.

Comment: Someone create Distribution cer, i can download it, but i don't hate private key. And i can't create new one. What shell i do?

Comment: You can select the cretificate and revoke the existing one and create a new one and install it on your keychain.

Comment: Is it "save". Won't it call some other problems with other apps? I i remember it won't, but i need to be sure :)

Comment: Yes it wont cause any problem for now. But make sure when you update the existing app just update the provisional with the new certificate. Also you need to regenerate the push certificates for the existing app if you have any

Comment: Oh, in this account about 20 apps in total. And almost all use APNS.

Comment: If you not recreate the APNS certificates when you resubmit the app then the APNS (pem)file which you uses in  back end will not send notifications for the device. So try to get the export copy from the person who create the certificate first and installed in their mac. If not then you need to recompile the APNS pem file for all the apps which you have!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40876/discussion-between-evgeniy-s-and-parthi)